# Evaluating the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am currently working on the problem.

Find $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{n+2}$$ when $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}x_{n}$ with $x_{0}=2$, $x_{1}=1$.

I was able to find $x_{n}$ to be $x_{n}=(\frac{1+i}{2})^n + (\frac{1-i}{2})^n$ which gives:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{1+i}{2})^n + (\frac{1-i}{2})^n}{n+2}$$

I was able to make a shift of the index, $m=n+2$, which gives:

$$\sum_{m=3}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac{1+i}{2})^{m-2} + (\frac{1-i}{2})^{m-2}}{m}$$

Some simplification and substitution I was able to get:

$$4 \sum_{m=3}^{\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{2})^m}{m(2)^m} \sin(\frac{m\pi}{4})$$

I have tried to look at the partial sums but that did not help that much. I am not sure on where to go from here. If anyone can offer a hint to guide me, that would be extremely helpful. Thank you for looking.

Also, during my simplification I found that:

$$-2i \sum_{m=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m(2)^m} [(1+i)^{m} - (1-i)^{m}]$$

Looking at the expansion of $(1+i)^{m} - (1-i)^{m}$, the real parts cancel out leaving only the imaginary terms. I am not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: If Im not wrong the series converges absolutely so from here you can separate the series in two (or four) geometric series depending of the sector of sine function. Then rewrite index of all these four series and evaluate each one separately noticing that the term $1/m$ can be seen as a term of the integration of a power.

Comment: Notice your series look a lot like the taylor series for log()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. An approach. One may recall that,
$$
-\log(1-z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}n, \quad |z|<1,\tag1
$$ where $\displaystyle  \log (z)$ denotes the principal value of the logarithm defined by 
 \begin{align} 
  \displaystyle \log (z)  = \ln |z| + i \: \mathrm{arg}z, \quad -\pi <\mathrm{arg} z \leq \pi,\quad z \neq 0. \nonumber
\end{align}
By applying $(1)$ we obtain,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\big(\frac{1+i}2\big)^n+\left(\frac{1-i}2\right)^n}{n+2}&=2\:\Re \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\big(\frac{1+i}2\big)^n}{n+2}
\\&=2\:\Re\left( 2i\log\left(\frac{1-i}2 \right)-\frac32+i\right)
\\&=\Re\left( \pi-3 +i\frac{}{} (2-2 \ln 2)\right)
\\&=\pi-3,
\end{align}
$$ where we have used  $$\displaystyle 2\:\Re\left( 2i\log\left(\frac{1-i}2 \right)\right)=2\:\Re\left(2i\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}2e^{\large-i\frac{\pi}4} \right)\right)=\pi.$$

Finally

> $$
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{n}}{n+2}=\pi-3.
> $$

Comment: @Joseph Are you Ok with the answer above? Feel free to ask for more information, if needed.

Comment: Yes your hint helped me in the completion of my problem. Thank you. @Olivier Oloa

Comment: @Joseph You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Indeed, you don't need the $\ds{x_{n}\ \mbox{v.s.}\ n}$ explicit expression. You can 'jump' right away into the generating function.

---

With $\ds{\quad x_{0} =2\,,\quad x_{1} = 1}$:

\begin{align}
0 & = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{2\,x_{n + 2} - 2\,x_{n +1} + x_{n}}z^{n + 3} =
2\sum_{n = 2}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1} - 2z\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1} +
z^{2}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1}
\\[4mm] & =
2\pars{-x_{1}\,z^{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1}} -
2z\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1} + z^{2}\pars{x_{0}\,z +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1}}
\\[4mm] & =
2z^{3} - 2z^{2} + \pars{2 - 2z + z^{2}}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1}
\end{align}

---

$$
\imp\quad\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_{n}\,z^{n + 1} =
-2\,{z^{3} - z^{2} \over z^{2} - 2z + 2}
$$

---

Integrate both sides over $\ds{\pars{0,1}}$:
$$
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{x_{n} \over n + 2}} =
-2\int_{0}^{1}{z^{3} - z^{2} \over z^{2} - 2z + 2}\,\dd z =
\color{#f00}{\pi - 3}
$$